# Unable to install TensorFlow 2.2.0 either by pip or by conda

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I got error in both jupyter notebook and conda prompt as i run the code to install TensorFlow 2.2.0

As i use `pip install tensorflow==2.2.0` in jupyter notebook, i got this error

> Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
> Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.

And as i use `conda install tensorflow==2.2.0` again i got the error

> PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:
>
> - tensorflow==2.2.0

Comment: Why do you want 2.2.0?

Comment: For such an old version of tensorflow, you will probably need to specify the python version to be 3.8. https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/2.2.0/#files That shows all of the available 2.2.0 wheels, although conda might use different channels.